# Translate english to chinese using php

Tags: php, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [language translation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163454/language-translation-in-php)

I have data stored in the database in english. I want to show them in chinese language.

How can I do this? I already tried `iconv` but that seems to be used to change the encoding not for translation.  Wanted to know how can I perform this with PHP

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. Google is your friend.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/translate/

Comment: @alfasin You think PHP has built-in dictionary/context lists for all languages? It would be enormous. It's quite obvious that there is no built-in function to do this.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I didn't say that and nobody mentioned a "built-in function". And, there might be open-source libraries that do that, free APIs etc.

Comment: For example, see @glavić's comment!

Comment: @alfasin I was going by "I tried `iconv`"... This is why I said to Google; there are of course third-party libraries that will do this. It's still a poor question, and one that's been asked over and over.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to translate your website there are two types of content :

-formatable contents like date or messages that can be handled by the IntlExtension. For example

```
$today = new DateTime;
//if you do not use Intl 
echo $today->format('Y-m-D');//in english :-(
//with IntlDateFormatter
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter( "de-DE" ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
 IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
'America/Los_Angeles',IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN  );
echo $formatter->format($today);//in german
```

If you want to translate non formatable strings, such as headlines, or even content, you have two solutions :

- [GoogleTranslate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/)
- using a translater tool that you configure by giving yourself all the translations. There is [gettext](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.gettext.php) or the [Symfony translater component](https://github.com/symfony/Translation)